# Passing Array in where condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using following stored in sqlserver, I can't figure out to pass array in this stored procedure. The array is exactly in this format from c# code ABC,DEF or i can write string abc = "ABC,DEF";

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BookedChemicalsLists]
        @RigNameValue VARCHAR(50) = null
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;   

      SELECT *
      FROM [BookedChemicals]
      WHERE AND (RigName IN (@RigNameValue,',') OR @RigNameValue IS NULL )
END
```

Comment: I agree this is a duplicate, however, don't use the first 2 answers.

Comment: Can you please guide based on my query, i can't understand anything from there, it is different from what i am trying to do.

Comment: Yes please, i can;t find solution from those questions.

Comment: which version of SQL Server - that duplicate question specifically stated SQL Server 2008 and there are better ways to do it now.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2017

Comment: Thanks, i found the answer:

Comment: (RigName IN (SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(@RigNameValue, ',')) OR @RigNameValue IS NULL )

Comment: SQL Server 17 supports STRING_SPLIT which is heaven for me.